# Upload file from frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend, file-upload

I want to Provide an option for uploading file [ ex : image ] As it is default magento feature, its not visible in product view page

these 3 files are exists :

```
 app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/catalog/product/view/options/file.phtml

 app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml

 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml
```

in 3rd file inside node , below code exists:

```
config->global->catalog->product->options->custom->groups

<file translate="label" module="adminhtml">
    <label>File</label>
    <render>adminhtml/catalog_product_edit_tab_options_type_file</render>
    <types>
        <file translate="label" module="adminhtml">
            <label>File Upload</label>
        </file>
    </types>
</file>
```

Is i need to check in any other place ?

Comment: please explain your question a bit more

Comment: @User34444 Thanks for reply. all i wanted is uploading an product image front frontend [ product view page ] , this is default magento feature ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default **File upload** option will not visible in magento.

we need to create custom option for this from Backend.

once we Create custom option as below image, it will visible in frontend.

[image]